# How to represent fixed and unknown expressions together using Regular Expression in R?

Tags: r, regex

I am new to Regex, and I am trying to extract "@" and "vs" from a chunk of HTML code.

The pattern I found that before the @s and vs I want, there are always "game-status"> before them.

So, it either `"game-status">vs` or `"game"-status">@`

I plan to do `"[[:punct:]]{2}@|vs"` as my regex, but this does not seem to work.

Can anyone advice me how to fix this? And also in general, how to represent fixed expression together with the part that uses regex?

Thank you!

Comment: `"[[:punct:]]{2}(@|vs)"` or `"game-status[[:punct:]]{2}(@|vs)"` or `"game-status\">(@|vs)"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The pattern I found that before the @s and vs I want, there are always "game-status"> before them.

You may match the `"game-status">` fixed string first, then discard it with the `\K` operator (that is supported by the PCRE regex engine, you will need `perl=TRUE`), and then use a `(?:@|vs)` alternation group to match either `@` or `vs` (since these alternatives are of different length, you cannot use a character class):

```
x <- c('"game-status">vs', '"game-status">@')
unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr('"game-status">\\K(?:@|vs)', x, perl=TRUE)))
## => [1] "vs" "@"
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/64Nq8t).

Regarding your pattern, you may just use alternation groups. If you need to replace `@` and `vs`, you may use a capturing group (that is, `(...)`) around the pattern you need to keep and use a non-capturing one (`(?:...)`) when you need to remove a part of the string.

So, it might look like

```
gsub("([[:punct:]]{2})(?:@|vs)", "\\1<REPLACED>", x)
## => [1] "\"game-status\"><REPLACED>" "\"game-status\"><REPLACED>"
```